# Submit button not working in dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using javascript in my index.html file to load a login php page with another javascript form, if I go straight to the login.php page then the submit button works  just fine, but once it's loaded in my index.html file it won't do anything even though visually everything has loaded correctly on my screen.

Here's my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='myStyle'></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myStyle').load('./login.php');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the login.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forms.js"></script>
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if(isset($_GET['error'])) { 
  if($_GET['error']==1) {
    echo 'Error Logging In!';
  }
}
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {
  header('Location: ./registration.php');
} else {
?>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Sprinkler Controller - Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="0" align="center">
    <form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
       <tr>
       <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td colspan ="2" align="center"><input type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /></td>
       </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Notice that the login.php loads a form from forms.js

```
function formhash(form, password) {
   // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
   var p = document.createElement("input");
   // Add the new element to our form.
   form.appendChild(p);
   p.name = "p";
   p.type = "hidden"
   p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
   // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
   password.value = "";
   // Finally submit the form.
   form.submit();
}
```

Reading around a little I think that I need to add something to the tune of

```
$(document).on('submit', '#password', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
})
```

But not only am I not certain which file and where in said file I would need to place it, I'm not certain if that's what I really need to do to fix it!

Comment: this is the FORM which fire submit event, not the INPUT

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Can you verify that formhash is executing?  From jQuery API "Script Execution: When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded."

Comment: @Daniel, from what little I understand about js debugging, the answer appears to be no, I can't see that formhash is executing for some reason.  When I go straight to the php page, everything works with no issue whatsoever.

Comment: To be specific, in firebug it shows that it get's to this onclick event ----- function onclick(event) {
formhash(this.form, this.form.password);
} -----  and then dies

Comment: The error message I get when it fails is "TypeError: this.form is null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking around I found that the overall issue was that I was attempting to load an entire HTML page inside my login.php file into a DIV.  I ditched the index.html file and just go straight to login.php instead of trying to wrap it inside an html page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='myStyle'></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myStyle').load('./login.php');
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault();
    })
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This behaves in the exact same manner as the original code unfortunately.